# Creating and building C++ shared library using Eclipse on Mac and getting .so file

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, shared-libraries

I've created a C++ shared library in order to export it into Android Studio as a native library.

The output file that can be imported by Android Studio is the .so file, but I'm getting only .dylib

I'm building on Mac and used MacOSX GCC compiler when I created the library.

[image]

Comment: Your output is dylib because of you are using gcc for MAC. You need to cross compile your code to create a .so shared lib.

Comment: @LPs, you're right. But when I choose Cross GCC then I'm asked to enter cross compiler prefix and path, which I don't know where to get from.

Comment: You wrote about Android Studio. Use it instead of eclipse to generate your shared lib.